# Does it make sense to combine JIT'ed code with MPI to enhance performance?

Tags: compiler, hpc, performance

I'm writing a package for solving computationally intensive systems of equations. I'm already using `LLVM` for just-in-time compilation but I'm now looking into parallelizing these algorithms for 1) additional performance and 2) to make use of HPC systems. Therefore I'm looking into the possibility of using MPI for distributing the computation accross multiple nodes. Therefore my question: does it make sense to combine LLVM JIT'ed code with MPI distributed computing?

Comment: Note: I wanted to tag this question with: LLVM, JIT and MPI but didn't have the rep points to create the tags.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending software meeting specific requirements – not approaches, [languages](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185), [technologies](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/185) or [algorithms](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/185).

Comment: Apologies, I thought it would get shot down on stackoverflow...

Comment: Ah, and now it got shot down here instead, oops… Not sure if SO would shoot it or not, I'm not that active over there.